# Generate Tree View from XML in VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, xml

Below is my XML:-

```
<Category>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Name>Root</Name>
  <Type>NA</Type>
  <Children>
    <Category>
      <ID>3</ID>
      <Name>Ritter Comm</Name>
      <Type>Operating Group</Type>
      <Children>
        <Category>
          <ID>5</ID>
          <Name>Product Line</Name>
          <Type>Product Line</Type>
          <Children>
            <Category>
              <ID>6</ID>
              <Name>Video</Name>
              <Type>Category</Type>
              <Children>
                <Category>
                  <ID>8</ID>
                  <Name>TV</Name>
                  <Type>component</Type>
                  <Children />
                </Category>
              </Children>
            </Category>
          </Children>
        </Category>
      </Children>
    </Category>
    <Category>
      <ID>10</ID>
      <Name>Test_Changeset</Name>
      <Type>Operating Group</Type>
      <Children>
        <Category>
          <ID>11</ID>
          <Name>Changeset</Name>
          <Type>Product Line</Type>
          <Children />
        </Category>
      </Children>
    </Category>
  </Children>
</Category>
```

I want to generate a tree view structure in Visualforce Page like below:-

`-Root
    -Ritter Comm
        -Product Line
            -Video
                -TV
    -Test_Changeset
        -Changeset`

I'm using apex:repeat, but how we will know for how many times the apex:repeat tag to be used based on the level depth?
Any ideas much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

1. Using dynamic VF in Apex (traverse through the XML and generate components as you hit leaf nodes)
2. Using Javascript/jQuery in VF (process the XML directly on the client side)
3. Or maybe this: http://www.forcetree.com/2011/04/tree-view-in-visualforce-page.html

Comment: Thanks... in that link the level of hierarchy is fied - Account,Contact Last name & Cases.

Comment: But in this scenario it varies dynamically.How we will take care of that?